# save RData workspace in Python using rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Another rpy2 related question pertaining to converting deprecated rpy code to its rpy2 equivalent.  In my python script I have a for loop statement that simply passes inputs across a series of matrices.  At the end, I save it to a .RData workspace to be loaded again and looped through 2 more times.

In rpy, the save file was written as this:

```
#Save resulting RDATA workspace (.RDATA file)
rpy.r.save_image()
```

I have tried, without success

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro 
from rpy2robjects import r

ro.r.save_image()
```

Also, I have another python script that has this, which I have tried using ro.r as well, with no luck:

`#Write out success variable
rpy.r("success = TRUE")
rpy.r("save(success,file='success.RData')")`

If anyone out there has a clue as to how to how to translate the above "rpy.r." statements into rpy2 equivalency, I would appreciate guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If staying with rpy2 to load the saved objects, you could just use Python's pickling (the equivalent of R's load/save - see http://pymotw.com/2/pickle/):
http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.4/html/robjects_serialization.html

Otherwise try:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
base = importr('base')
base.save_image(<arguments here...>)
```

Comment: I am using ro.r.load() to load the saved objects.  That syntax seems to work ok.  But it is saving the images to disk that I am having issues with.  I read the robjects serialization but I am not following it (noob here)...could you please provide a working example of this?

Comment: Done (in the answer).

Comment: Thanks @lgautier.  Also, another avenue that I discovered, and tested successfully (for those who wish to know) is that rpy_classic will translate the save_image() to rpy2 as well.  Many different ways to skin a cat in rpy2. :)